# Express $\cos$ and $\sin$ values

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

I don't really now how to explain this in English, but I'll do my best:

> Write this $\cos\frac{1}{2}t + \sin\frac{1}{2}t$ in the form $A \cos(\omega t-\phi)$

It would have been nice if someone could explain me how and why the expression is like what its gonna be

Comment: What are you having trouble understanding?

Comment: Actually i dont get the problem...as in how am I gonna transform it in into "A cos..."

Comment: @namrah93: An edit has been made to your post. Is it the same as the question given to you?

Comment: @Nick yeah thats the question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems a hint may not be sufficient, so here's an approach to the answer. Please note my angles are in degrees.

$$\large cos(\frac{t}{2})+sin(\frac{t}{2})$$

If you're sufficiently familiar with trigonometric identities, you would realize that $$ \large \cos A \cdot \cos B - \sin A \cdot \sin B = \cos (A-B)$$

We can apply this identity to our equation after we perform a little trick.
I think you already know that $\cos(45) = \sin(45) = \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}$

Now, there's nothing wrong if I do this to the given equation,
$$\large \sqrt 2 \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\cdot (\space\cos(\frac{t}{2})+sin(\frac{t}{2})\space)$$
$$\large\Rightarrow \sqrt 2 \cdot (\space\cos(\frac{t}{2})\cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}+sin(\frac{t}{2})\cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\space)$$
$$\large\Rightarrow \sqrt 2 \cdot (\space\cos(\frac{t}{2})\cdot \sin(45) +sin(\frac{t}{2})\cdot \cos(45)\space)$$
Now, applying our identity,
$$\large\Rightarrow \sqrt 2\cdot (\frac{1}{2}\cdot t - 45 )$$

Hey, isn't that the form you were looking for?

I hope this helped and as advice for future questions, try to correlate the given question and the identities you know. It helps a lot in all kinds of questions.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Expand $\cos(\omega t - \phi)$ using the formula
$$\cos (\alpha - \beta) = \cos \alpha \cos \beta + \sin \alpha \sin \beta$$
and choose values for $A$, $\omega$ and $\phi$ so that both sides match up.

Comment: I'm sorry, I still dont get it :/ The answer is √2 cos (1/2t - π/4)

Comment: @namrah93: I'd be surprised if there aren't any examples like this in whichever textbook you're using (or class/lecture notes). Notice
$$A\cos(\omega t - \phi) = A\cos (\omega t) \cos \phi + A\sin(\omega t)\sin \phi$$
So you need $\omega = \frac{1}{2}$, $A\cos \phi = 1$ and $A\sin \phi = 1$. Solve these last two equations for $A$ and $\phi$ and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

$$\cos(t/2) + \sin(t/2) = \sqrt{2}(\cos(t/2)\cos(\pi/4) + \cos(t/2)\sin(\pi/4))
= \sqrt{2}(\cos(t/2 - \pi/4).$$